# How can I use interrupt/kill signal with noncanonical mode?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, signals, termios

This is a code that get character without pressing enter.

```
int getch(FILE *cmd)
{
    int ch;
    struct termios buf;
    struct termios info;

    tcgetattr(0, &info);
    buf = info;
    buf.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO); // noncanonical
    buf.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    buf.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    // buf.c_cc[VINTR];
    // buf.c_cc[VKILL];

    tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &buf);
    ch = getc(cmd);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &info);

    return ch;
}
```

In this code, how can I use interrupt/kill signal with noncanonical mode?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to modify `c_iflag` appropriately. See `BRKINT` and `IGNBRK` flags.